# JS output to a html input

Tags: javascript, html, input

Need the output of the time script to change the input of a input field but can't figure it out.

---

```
<script>
function addZero(i) {
if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i;
}
return i;
}

function checkouttimeFunction() {
var d = new Date();
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
var h = addZero(d.getHours());
var m = addZero(d.getMinutes());
var s = addZero(d.getSeconds());
x.innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
var elem = document.getElementById("cout");
elem.value = document.getElementById("demo");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are the functions actually called from another script or from the html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the innerHTML text of x to be displayed in the input field elem.

You cant set the 'value' attribute to an HTML element, but you can instead just set it to the desired text (e.g the time).

```
<script>
function addZero(i) {
if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i;
}
return i;
}

function checkouttimeFunction() {
var d = new Date();
var h = addZero(d.getHours());
var m = addZero(d.getMinutes());
var s = addZero(d.getSeconds());
var elem = document.getElementById("cout");
elem.value = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Yes value is right for sure. But you cant set a element as value.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like on the last line in `checkouttimeFunction()` you want do to:

```
elem.value = x.innerHTML;
```

Other than:

```
elem.value = document.getElementById("demo");
```

As you are trying to set the `value` to be a DOM element.

**[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/a3wabhf8/)**

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
elem.value = document.getElementById("demo");
```

to

```
elem.value = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
```

That should give you what you need. Because you need the content of the element and document.getElementById() will just give you the element, Which will be in the form of an Object.

Hope this helps.